# Mersive Solstive API: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'm_displayInformation'

Tags: python, json, api, get, ip

I have around 100 machines running Mersive Solstice, which is a wireless display tool. I'm trying to gather a few important pieces of information, in particular the fulfillment ID for the license for each installed instance.

Using the Solstice OpenControl API, found [here](http://assistly-production.s3.amazonaws.com/194551/kb_article_attachments/101899/Solstice-OpenControl-API-12-15-2016_original.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNSFWOZ6ZS23BMKQ&Expires=1495638187&Signature=Mze4tDSTiw5gstCisxil3ofpKcE%3D&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22Solstice-OpenControl-API-12-15-2016.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf), I whipped up a python script to grab everything I needed using a json GET. However, even when using the example GET from the documentation,

```
import requests
import json
url = ‘http://ip-of-machine/api/stats’

r = requests.get(url)
jsonStats = json.loads(r.text)
usersConnected = jsonStats.m_statistics.m_connectedUsers
```

I encounter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    usersConnected = jsonStats.m_statistics.m_connectedUsers
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'm_statistics'
```

Which is very confusing. I've found plenty of similar questions on SO regarding this problem, but not one that's been specifically regarding wrong GET requests from the API Reference guide.

Additionally, here is my script:

```
import requests
import json
from time import sleep

url = 'test'

f = open("ip.txt", "r")
while(url != ""):
    url = f.readline()
    url = url.rstrip('\n')
    print(url)

    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except:
        sleep(5)

    jsonConfig = json.loads(r.text)
    displayName = jsonConfig.m_displayInformation.m_displayName
    hostName = jsonConfig.m_displayInformation.m_hostName
    ipv4 = jsonConfig.m_displayInformation.m_ipv4
    fulfillmentId = jsonConfig.m_licenseCuration.fulfillmentId
    r.close()


f.close
```

I import the URL's from a text document for easy keeping. I'm able to make the connection to the /api/config JSON, and when the URL is put into a browser it does spit out the JSON records:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json uses "Dicts" which are a type of array. You are just using them in the wrong way. I recommend reading [Python Data Structures.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
Json.Loads()
```

Returns a dictionary not a object. Do:

```
dict['key']['key']
```

Here is how your code should look:

```
import requests
import json
from time import sleep

url = 'test'

f = open("ip.txt", "r")

while(url != ""):

    url = f.readline()
    url = url.rstrip('\n')
    print(url)

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_object = json.loads(response .text)
        displayName = json_object['m_displayInformation']['m_displayName']
        hostName = json_object['m_displayInformation']['m_hostName']
        ipv4 = json_object['m_displayInformation']['m_ipv4']
        fulfillmentId = json_object['m_licenseCuration']['fulfillmentId']
    except:
        pass

    response .close()
f.close()
```

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: About 5 minutes ago I decided to switch my notation from dot to bracket, and that certainly did the trick. I came back to self answer, however you described the problem much better than I could have! Cheers!